# Finiteness of Stopping Times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm reading a book about Brownian Motion and the write the following lemma:

> Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a d-dimensional Brownian Motion and $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded set. Then $E^x[\tau_D] < \infty$ ($\tau_D$ is the first hitting time of $D$)

They proceed to use it in the following propostion:

> If $u$ is continous and $u(B_{t \wedge \tau_G})$ is a martinagle with repect to the law $P^x$ of a Brownian Motion $(B_t)$ started at any $x\in G$ then $u$ has the spherical mean value property. (Here $G$ is a bounded open set in $D$)

The proof starts by considering a small ball $B \subset \bar{G} \subset D$ and defining $\tau_B$ as the exit time. They then assert $\tau_B < \infty$ by the first lemma I wrote.

I don't see why this is true - the lemma only says the expectation is finite. There could be some measure zero sets that blow up - violating $\tau_B < \infty$. What did I miss?

(For those curious: this is Lemma 8.8 and the first part of the proof of Thm 8.10 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ph7oBQAAQBAJ&q=be%20an%20open%20bounded%20Set.%20Then#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

Comment: They claim that $\tau_B$ is finite almost surely. This means you don't care what happens on the measure zero sets.

Comment: where do you see this? In the attached link pg 126, second paragraph, I don't see a.s. following the bound.

Comment: The almost surely is probably meant to be implied. Note that a couple of lines later they say "let us quickly check that $\tau$ is indeed a.s. finite". Note also that they only ever use a.s. finiteness of $\tau$.

Comment: okay, I guess optional stopping theorem can still be invoked in this case anyway

Comment: Expectation is finite is actually stronger than just a.s. finiteness (Think of symmetric RV hitting to 0.) and you can invoke OST in the former (with bounded increment assumption), but not latter. 

Unless specified, I think most people talk about a.s. equivalence in probability theory (since measure 0 sets don't matter if there aren't that many of them.)

Comment: @E-A Can you expand on your statement? My guess was that finite expectation and a.s finite would be the same thing. But if what you're saying is true, the lemma I'm reading is not relevant for the Proposition I'm reading!

Comment: @yoshi: No, they are not; the implication only goes one way. (If it had positive mass on infinity, it couldn't possibly have finite expectation). Think of the following RV X that has probability (1/2)^i on 3^i for i=1,2,... . Now, this variable is finite a.s., (Note that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} P(X < N) = 1$) but its expectation is infinite.